# How to install UBUNTU 14.04 when Mint is currently installed

Tags: 14.04, mint

Linux mint 16 cinnamon 32 bit
cinnamon version 2.0.14
linux kernel 3.11.0-20-generic

is it possible from terminal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can install from an existing Linux System using [debootstrap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux#Without_CD)

Comment: may you please give me more explicit instructions

Comment: If you look at the link I posted there is a step by step guide.